# Can we display username in salesforce header

Tags: javascript, org, username

I am currently working for multiple clients and frequently have to do data migration in their Production Org and have to keep on switching between different Orgs.
I want to know how can we put username in header as in attached file [image]

we have options for sandbox to identify  which sandbox we are logged in (on top right corner it shows sandbox name) but not for production instances.

Please suggest.

Comment: Its not possible to do that. But you could think about changing your user's name so that it appears on the right side. OR think about changing the icon shown on the left to something that will uniquely identify the org.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, the issue is that you have multiple production orgs, and you can't distinguish between them. Is that correct?

An option is to change the "logo" in the top left. Create an icon that reflects the functionality of the Org. Eg "Finance", "Overseas" etc.

You can also put a message box in the left sidebar.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=home_msgs.htm